# How to correctly use "Requires" option in systemd units?

Tags: systemd

after running this host with some self-written systemd services without issues for years, I got multiple complaints after I some planned maintenance that required mariadb to be sut down for a while. Turns out that I had put

```
Requires = mariadb.service
```

in the unit files, and those units terminated due to dependency conflicts while mariadb was down.

This is not surprising, but somewhat dangerous because apparently systemd doesn't automatically check if units that are stopped due to a service being temporarily down can be restarted when the depended-on service is up again.

I simply removed the dependency and let the services deal with the missing database; worst case they will crash and get re-startd by systemd automatically.

Are there any "cleaner" methods out there? How can I know that I don't accidentally kill some essential system service the same way?

Yes, I read this: [Understanding systemd "Requires=" option.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390898/understanding-systemd-requires-option) But it deals with a different problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen. Should your units be stopped when mariadb is stopped and started when mariadb is started? Then you want `BindsTo`, not just `Requires`.

Comment: I think OP wants `mariadb` to start when this unit is started, but does not want this unit to stop if `mariadb` is stopped.  `Requires=` seems right here unless mariadb stays in the `activating` state.   But if you want to weaken the dependency, use `Wants=`.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=

Comment: I don't mind the unit stopping when mariadb is stopped (because it can't work without it anyway). I wasn't aware of two things: 1) That my unit stops when mariadb stops (because I didn't RTFM), and 2) that it wouldn't automatically restart once mariadb is up again. Will look into BindsTo. Thanks!